# Function misunderstanding

Tags: c, windows, function, struct, archive

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Forca // definining struct here
{
    char palavra[TAM_PALAVRA];
    char palavra_mascarada[TAM_PALAVRA];
    int erros, acertos, tentativas;

} t_forca;
void salva_jogo(t_forca forca) //function that writes structure inside bin file
{
    FILE* save;
    save = fopen("save.bin", "w+b");
    if (save == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nerro no arquivo\n");
    }
    fwrite(&forca, sizeof(forca), 1, save);
    fclose(save);
}
void carrega_jogo(t_forca* forca) //function that read struct inside bin file
{
    FILE* readsave;
    readsave = fopen("save.bin", "r+b");
    if (readsave == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nerro no arquivo\n");
    } //printf error
    fread(forca, sizeof(forca), 1, readsave);
    fclose(readsave);
}
```

basically I'm trying to save and read a structure inside a binary file, and I'm quite lost cuz the file is being written but not read at all

Comment: `forca` is a pointer in read function. change `sizeof(forca)` to `sizeof(t_forca)`

Comment: you are right thx

Comment: it solved the problem, but can you help me, in this one, is saying that both functions have conflicting types and i don't know why

Comment: it's just a warning tho

Comment: After adding a missing definition for `TAM_PALAVRA`, the code appears to compile without any warnings. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qG5nsYqcW

Comment: I don't know which functions you are talking about.

Comment: oh sorry, for my stupid question, the reason why is cuz i did something wrong

Comment: the reason why, is because i din't declare in my original code the funciton before using also

Comment: but thx, you realy saved me with that size of over there, i wasted 3 hours trying to find the problem, i looked up everything

Comment: if you post it as an answer i can check it as an answer

Comment: because it's really the only thing that was lacking in my code

Comment: thx alot man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `carrega_jogo`, `forca` is a pointer, `sizeof(forca)` is the same as size of pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system or compiler settings. The read function ends up reading only 4 or 8 bytes. The rest of the structure is likely uninitialized and leads to undefined behavior.

The correct version should be `sizeof(t_forca)`

Aside, for `fwrite/fread` it is enough `"wb"` and `"rb"`.